# SignalR as a WCF Binding

Tags: c#, wcf, signalr

I'm using REST, TCP and WsHTTP based WCF services in my app.

Is there any way to use SignalR as part of WCF as a WCF Binding? If it's not available now, are there any plans for that?

Thanks

Comment: WCF bindings define transport and protocol, SignalR is none of those.

Comment: In older versions of .Net, we had remoting which was then replaced by WCF. I'm wondering if SignalR will soon become a part of WCF? Isn't WCF the way to go for SignalR? Isn't the transport JSON and protocol http in this case?

Comment: I believe it could be possible to create an WCF IDuplex[Session]Channel implementation based on SignalR's low level PersistentConnection API. The question is: why would you want to? What would the benefit above just using SignalR's native APIs? Are you thinking of exposing the same WCF service over multiple endpoints and want to be able to do so agnostically?